# how to calculate pre and post measures degrees of freedom across participants

Tags: regression, statistical-power

I have 10 participant and I want to measure if there is a correlation between their main measure and a clinical condition. I want to know how to calculate the degree of freedom pre and post measures across all participant ?

I know df = n-2 but this is for post measure

Answer (score 0):

The analysis you are looking for is called a repeated measures anova because it is specifically designed for analyses where the same subject is measured multiple times. This analysis has two degrees of freedom that need to be recorded: A) the number of repeated measurements minus 1 (you have 2 per subject so your df here is 1) and for the subjects where you just add up the per subject df (in this case it's 10*1 because 10 subjects and 1 df per subject).

Here is an excellent reference that shows all the steps and how to calculate the degrees of freedom: https://www.discoveringstatistics.com/repository/onewayrmhand.pdf

or here: https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/repeated-measures-anova-statistical-guide-2.php